# Does Sauce lab needs authenticate to run tests which are in client side?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-grid, saucelabs

Let's say I have a jenkins ci/cd pipeline in network-1 where it connects to git repo to checkout the code and do the deployment in network-2.

now after the deployment, selenium functional test cases has to run so jenkins is doing 1st time authentication to connect to sauce labs.

once it connects to sauce labs, does sauce labs also need to do the 2nd time authentication to connect the site under test which may be running in network-2 ?

In total how many authentications should happen in ideal scenario where security must be there ?

Does jenkins has a way to check the status(up or down) of the selenium grid which is running in the sauce lab environment.

how does sauce lab will transfer the test results report from sauce lab to jenkins dashboard ?

Comment: Hi there!  You've asked three different questions here; I've answered the first.  
Keeping answers to a single, well, question, helps other developers find and answer them in the future; Can you go ahead and open two other questions asking about Status Checks and Test Results?  If you drop a link here in the comments, I'll be able to go answer those as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Authenticating Traffic

As you identified, there are two, totally separate streams of traffic during a Sauce Labs Webdriver test:

**The Control Stream** between your test runner and the Sauce Labs WebDriver server and

**The Traffic Stream** between the browser under control and the system under test

The Control Stream is a standard HTTPS connection; It's an outgoing connection from your servers to Sauce Labs.  If your network infrastructure is set up to allow all outgoing connections, this will work fine.

The Traffic Stream is another matter.  Sauce Labs browsers will be able to request traffic from your system under test without config if:

1. The system is being addressed by a full, valid domain name (not an internal domain name)
2. Your network is set up to allow *incoming* network requests to this  address.

Most of the time, this is not the case.  However, Sauce Labs does provide a free tool to securely send the Traffic Stream, called [Sauce Connect](https://docs.saucelabs.com/secure-connections/).

## How Sauce Connect Works

To allow Sauce Labs to connect to your system under test with Sauce Connect, you need to run the Sauce Connect client inside your network, from a host that is able to contact the System Under Test.

Once that's set up properly, it'll work like this:

1. You start the Sauce Connect client on your infrastructure
2. Sauce Labs starts a new, secure Sauce Connect host on their infrastructure
3. Your test runner starts a new WebDriver session
4. Sauce Labs starts a fresh session, configured to use Sauce Connect
5. Your Test Runner sends a request-1 to open your site (Let's call it *internal.test*
6. Sauce Labs' browser sends request-2 to get *https://internal.test* from the Sauce Connect host
7. The Sauce Connect host passes the request securely to the Sauce Connect client
8. The Sauce Connect client uses your network's local DNS setup to resolve the address of *internal.test*, then requests the traffic from that server
9. The server responds
10. The Sauce Connect sends the response back to the Sauce Connect Host
11. The Sauce Connect Host sends the response back to the browser
12. Sauce Labs' sends a response to request-1, indicating that the page has loaded.

(*Please excuse the detail; I work for Sauce Labs and have found that it can be very helpful to detail exactly what the order of operations is*)

## TL;DR

You **will** have to set up Sauce Connect if your System Under Test isn't available from the general Internet.  Sauce Connect has to be started on a machine that can contact your System Under Test.

You can either leave a Sauce Connect session running in [High Availability](https://docs.saucelabs.com/secure-connections/sauce-connect/setup-configuration/high-availability/) mode, or start a new Sauce Connect tunnel every time you run tests.  If you're able to start a High Availability tunnel on network-2, I would suggest that; It will lower test start times and, once operational, should function mostly seamlessly if you also set up Rolling Restarts.

Sauce Labs also has a [Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sauce-ondemand/) that can start Sauce Connect for you before each test run.  This will only work if the Jenkins host machine can contact the System Under Test.